# Avoiding external disk sort for aggregate query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

We have a table that contains raw analytics (like Google Analytics and similar) numbers for views on our videos. It contains numbers like raw views, downloads, loads, etc. Each video is identified by a video_id.

Data is recorded per-day, but because we need to extract on a number of metrics each day can contain multiple records for a specific video_id. Example:

```
date       | video_id | country | source   | downloads | etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-02 |        1 |      us | facebook |        10 |
2014-01-02 |        1 |      dk | facebook |        13 |
2014-01-02 |        1 |      dk | admin    |        20 |
```

I have a query where I need to get aggregate data for all videos that have new data beyond a certain date. To get the video ID's I do this query: `SELECT video_id FROM table WHERE date >= '2014-01-01' GROUP BY photo_id` (alternatively I could do a `DISTINCT(video_id)` without a GROUP BY, performance is identical).

Once I have these IDs I need the total aggregate data (for all time). Combined, this turns into the following query:

```
SELECT
    video_id,
    SUM(downloads),
    SUM(loads),
    <more SUMs),
FROM
    table
WHERE
    video_id IN (SELECT video_id FROM table WHERE date >= '2014-01-01' GROUP BY video_id)
GROUP BY
    video_id
```

There is around ~10 columns we SUM (5-10 depending on the query). The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` gives the following:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=2370840.59..2475948.90 rows=42537 width=72) (actual time=153790.362..162668.962 rows=87661 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2370840.59..2378295.16 rows=2981826 width=72) (actual time=153790.329..155833.770 rows=3285001 loops=1)
        Sort Key: table.video_id
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 263528kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=57066.94..1683266.53 rows=2981826 width=72) (actual time=740.210..143814.921 rows=3285001 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (table.video_id = table.video_id)
              ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..1550549.52 rows=5963652 width=72) (actual time=1.768..47613.953 rows=5963652 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=56924.17..56924.17 rows=11422 width=8) (actual time=734.881..734.881 rows=87661 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=56695.73..56809.95 rows=11422 width=8) (actual time=693.769..715.665 rows=87661 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using table_recent_ids on table  (cost=0.00..52692.41 rows=1601328 width=8) (actual time=1.279..314.249 rows=1614339 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (date >= '2014-01-01'::date)
                                Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 162693.367 ms
```

As you can see, it's using a (quite big) external disk merge sort and taking a long time. I am unsure of why the sorts are triggered in the first place, and I am looking for a way to avoid it or at least minimize it. I know increasing `work_mem` can alleviate external disk merges, but in this case it seems to be excessive and having a work_mem above 500MB seems like a bad idea.

The table has two (relevant) indexes: One on `video_id` alone and another on `(date, video_id)`.

EDIT: Updated query after running `ANALYZE table`.

Comment: Your execution plan doesn't really match your example query. You have a merge join in there which I can't match to the SQL you have shown us. Are you sure you are showing us everything?

Comment: It matches entirely, only thing I have changes is some names. I suspect the merge join is an optimization where the inner query is treated as a JOIN instead of as a list of values.

Comment: The join probably results from postgres converting the subselect into a join.

Comment: The `group by` in the sub-query is useless. Get rid of id, it's not needed. Plus the sub-select seems to be not needed at all as it selects from the same table as the outer query. This could be replaced with a simple `where date >= '2014-01-01'` condition

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: No, it cannot. I want the videos that have data after the specific date, but I want the aggregate data for those videos _for all time_ (not just after the given date). Hence, it cannot be combined.

Comment: Did a `ANALYZE table` and re-ran the query and got the above instead. It's different, but it still uses a huge external disk merge.

Comment: Ah, right. I overlooked that. But the `group by` is still useless in the sub-query the `IN` operator will implicitly do a `distinct`.

Comment: You could also try to replace the `in (...)` condition with an `exists (...)` condition and a co-related sub-query. I have seen queries run much faster that way.

Comment: It seems like it should be using a hash aggregate at the top level.  If you run the query with exactly the two `SUM` shown, how large do you have set work_mem before it switches to a hash agg at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited to match the revised query plan.*

You are getting a sort because Postgres needs to sort the result rows to group them.

This query looks like it could really benefit from an index on `table(video_id, date)`, or even just an index on `table(video_id)`.  Having such an index would likely avoid the need to sort.

*Edited (#2) to suggest*

You could also consider testing an alternative query such as this:

```
SELECT
    video_id,
    MAX(date) as latest_date,
    <SUMs>
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    video_id
HAVING
    latest_date >= '2014-01-01'
```

That avoids any join or subquery, and given an index on `table(video_id [, other columns])` it can be hoped that the sort will be avoided as well.  It *will* compute the sums over the whole base table before filtering out the groups you don't want, but that operation is O(*n*), whereas sorting is O(*m* log *m*).  Thus, if the date criterion is not very selective then checking it after the fact may be an improvement.

Comment: I should probably have clarified (will update the post). The table has an index on `video_id` itself and another called `table_recent_ids` that is (date, video_id).

Comment: It would be worthwhile to try adding an index on `table(video_id, date)` (in which case the existing index on `table(video_id)` would be superfluous).  If postgres were using such an index to perform the join then it should recognize that it does not need a separate sort.

Comment: Using this query is 33% faster than the original with just the (video_id, date) and the query plan is also far simpler. It's still doing a sort, will see what adding an index for the rest of the fields will do.